# Creating a thread in WebLogic

Tags: multithreading, weblogic12c

I have an application running on WebLogic 12.2.1. This application is consisted of JAX-RS web services. I need to create a background thread to periodically clean up files created by the web services. What would be the correct way to do so? I know how to create threads in stand-alone Java programs, but never done it on J2EE applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the JEE Timer Service http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Sample Implementation:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Timer {

// Triggers every 30 seconds from 6PM till 6AM
    @Schedule(second = "*/30", minute = "*", hour = "18-6", dayOfWeek = "*", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*", info = "Timer", persistent = false)
    public void produce() {
        LOGGER.info("Sending Signal");
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How do you instantiate the Timer class in the web application? Is this specify in web.xml?

Comment: I do not instantiate it myself, that's what the applicationserver does automatically. That's the good part about annotations, you don't need a xml configuration.

Comment: But how would the application server even knows the existence of this class? Surely you would have to specify this class somewhere so that the application server knows about it.

Comment: The application server scans all classes for annotations like @Schedule, this happens during start/deployment of the application. This is one of the reasons why deploying application takes some time. Try making a web application (war file) with only this class and watch the output on the console, it's really that simple

Comment: OK, I did put it in a WAR file and it magically works. Thanks!

Comment: How do I specify if I want it to run once a day at 3am only?

Comment: You change the values for second/minute/hour to a fixed value instead of a range, this should do: @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "2", dayOfWeek = "*", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*", info = "Timer", persistent = false). The values are zero-based. (Note, there are star symbols * between the seemingly empty quotation marks, they seem to disappear in the comments)

Comment: It seems that we can't specify "" for dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month and year. There must be a value.

Comment: Yeah, the comments unfortunately eat the star * symbol in between quotation marks.  This should work too @Schedule(hour = "2", info = "Timer", persistent = false)

Comment: I specified @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "2", info = "Timer", persistent = false), but it actually ran at 2am instead of 3am.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for letting me know. The documentation confused me there for a bit.